# HTML5 canvas, resize a background image

Tags: html, image, canvas

I have a canvas thas is created dynamically, so width and height are always differents.

I have a background image i want to put on this canvas, so i just add in CSS :

```
canvas { background:url(/URL/background-canvas.jpg) }
```

But, how can i auto resize the image to the size of my canvas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:

```css
canvas { 
    background: url('/URL/background-canvas.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) for more info on it.